# .NET Core 1.1, but installer says SDK 1.0.3?

Tags: .net-core

I'm confused about .NET Core and version numbers. I downloaded the .NET Core 1.1 Windows (x64) Installer (.exe). When the installer started to run, it says ".NET Core SDK 1.0.3 (x64) Setup". When I type "dotnet --version" from the command line, I also get "1.0.3".

Why doesn't the version information show "1.1"?

Comment: Unfortunately `.NET Core Runtime` and `.NET Core SDK` have different versions and it's by design: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

Comment: Thanks! So, how can I check the version of the .NET Core Runtime that is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core Runtime (binaries) and .NET Core SDK have different versions and it's by design:

[.NET Core Runtime and SDK download archive](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md).

For example, .NET Core Runtime `1.1.1` is distributed together with SDK `1.0.3`.

`dotnet --version` command returns latest SDK version.To check all SDK versions installed, go to

> c:\program files\dotnet\sdk

At this moment, `dotnet` doesn't provide a console command to print Runtime versions. You can track a discussion about it at GitHub:

[Add a CLI gesture to display installed SDKs/Runtimes in the host location](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6119).

**Workaround (Windows)**

It is possible to install multiple Runtime and SDK versions. To find all Runtimes installed, go to folder:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\

and check subfolders with installed Runtime binaries:

```
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.1.0
1.1.1
```

That is still actual for [.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingDotnetCore20AndDotnetCore1xVersionedSDKsOnTheSameMachine.aspx).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you @Ilya Chumakov

Answer (score 1):

The funny part is, the SDK is designed to be independent of the runtime i.e. The dotnet SDK is capable of running your app with different runtime versions, including .NET Framework (full framework) runtime. It's specified in your *.csproj (or *.fsproj)

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>`

So what happens is the SDK will look at that project file, and install the runtime if it's missing from your machine when you run `dotnet restore`.
You can get the current runtime version of the program by

`Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);`